# Biblatex no printing page number

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` package to produce my references, with the `ieee` style. This is what I have in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[style=ieee, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
```

The `biblio.bib` file is like this:

```
@inproceedings{
Angelosante2007, 
author={Daniele Angelosante and Ezio Biglieri and Marco Lops}, 
title={A Simple Algorithm for Neighbor Discovery in Wireless Networks}, 
booktitle={Acoustics, Speech and Signal Processing, 2007. ICASSP 2007. IEEE International Conference on},
editor={IEEE},
year=2007, 
month=april,
volume=3, 
number={}, 
pages={III-169--III-172},
doi={10.1109/ICASSP.2007.366499}, 
isbn={1-4244-0728-1},
keywords={limited-complexity constraints; missed detection; neighbor discovery; wireless networks; computational complexity; radio networks;},
}
```

Everything is OK, except that page is not appearing. If I change pages like `pages={169--172}` it does work. Or if I use:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{biblio}
```

It also prints the page range number.

How can I do for pages not following strictly the range rule to appear? Thanks.

Comment: A quick check suggests that the field is not passed through by Biber to LaTeX. You can get some output using BibTeX as the backend by writing `pages={{III-169}--{III-172}}`, but I'm not really sure that is what is wanted. Perhaps this is an issue in Biber: I will ask PLK to take a look.

Comment: I tried your solution but no luck!

What I want is that pages appear when reference is printed, like `pp. III-169--III-172`.

Sorry if I was not clear in what I want.

Comment: With BibTeX or with Biber? As I said, what comes through to LaTeX in the two cases is different. Also, I said 'some output': not perfect for what you want, perhaps. I'd also add that the comparison with `IEEEtran` is not necessarily informative: `biblatex` has a much stricter idea of what can go in some fields than 'traditional' BibTeX does.

Comment: Ok. I just put the `IEEEtran` as an example because the purpose of `style=ieee` in `biblatex` is to have the same behavior as the previous one.

Comment: The problem is that biber uses one or more dash characters as the range separator. The format you have can't be properly parsed as a range with two ends. I'll have to think about this.

Comment: Another thing I noticed, unrelated, is that you are attempting to use "april" as a bibtex month macro when it should be "apr". This will cause some errors, nothing to do with this issue though.

Comment: Yes. I already corrected that. It was a typo.

Returning to the problem, I do not know if it is related with biber. When I comment `backend=biber` and set `\bibliography{biblio.bib}` instead of `\addbibresource{biblio.bib}` the problem persists.

I would say the problem is related with `biblatex` parsing data instead of `biber`-only related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This issue is due to the range parsing on the backends (bibtex or biber). The manual does say that dashes are used to separate range beginning and end so technically your example shouldn't work according to the documentation. However, to deal with this, I've allowed biber to take note of braces for ranges so you should be able to do:

```
pages = {{III-169}--{III-172}}
```

now with biber 1.2 which is in the development folder on SourceForge.

Comment: Ok! I will update my `biber` version and try! I will reply later.

Comment: I have just updated the `TexLive 2012` installation. My `biber` version is 1.0. And for now I had no luck with the proposed solution.

Comment: You'll need to manually update by downloading biblatex 2.1 and biber 1.2 from SourceForge as the new versions are not in TexLive yet.

Comment: I do not know if there is other way of implement this. my concern is that in legacy `bibtex` the `@` symbol before an entry means that entry is to be ignored.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was a typo, corrected.

Comment: This still not working with biblatex 2.1 if the backend instead of biber is, e.g., bibtex; it only displays numbers but not `pp.`. Sometimes I prefer using `backend=bibtex` to use biblatex in a old shared machine where biber 1.2 is not installed.

Comment: I think you'll need to customise`\DeclareNumChars`, see the biblatex manual. "I" is not recognised as a part of a page number by default.

Comment: Thanks! Either `\DeclareNumChars{{}.}` or `\DeclareRangeChars{~,;-+/{}}` work for both biber or bibtex backends. Which one is preferable?

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter so much really, perhaps \DeclareRangeChars is more logical since the braces are there to protect compound ranges.